# How to output this HTML code in PHP?

Tags: php, html

```
<li class="moveUnit">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" class="currentItem">
    <img src="$picture[1]" alt="" ref1="$picture[1]" ref2="$picture[1]" onmouseover="Biz.Product.Product.ChangePic(this);" class="Picture40"/>
  </a>
</li>
```

by trying to put this line of code in php file, I found this line has reserved char that will not be allowed in php. Please help, I have tried `htmlspecialchars()`. Still, I don't know why it is not working.

Comment: I guess you guys are mislead by the code, I really mean is how to add this line in PHP. example like, echo out this line. Since this line has reserved characters, it will not work by just echo this line. So is there any way I can change it and then echo out this line? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is inside php tags (`<?php ?>`) it will need to be output using `echo();` like so:

```
<?php
echo '<li class="moveUnit"><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" class="currentItem"><img src="' . $picture[1] . '" alt="" ref1="' . $picture[1] . '" ref2="' . $picture[1] . '" onmouseover="Biz.Product.Product.ChangePic(this);" class="Picture40"/></a></li>' ;
?>
```

OR if it's not between, you can echo just those variables between HTML:

```
<li class="moveUnit"><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" class="currentItem"><img src="<?php echo $picture[1]; ?>" alt="" ref1="<?php echo $picture[1]; ?>" ref2="<?php echo $picture[1]; ?>" onmouseover="Biz.Product.Product.ChangePic(this);" class="Picture40"/></a></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have do it like this way

```
<li class="moveUnit"><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" class="currentItem"><img src="<?php echo $picture[1]; ?>" alt="" ref1="<?php echo $picture[1]; ?>" ref2="<?php echo $picture[1]; ?>" onmouseover="Biz.Product.Product.ChangePic(this);" class="Picture40"/></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to print the line just create a string variable with single quotes:

```html
<?php
$string = '<li class="moveUnit"><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" class="currentItem"><img src="$picture[1]" alt="" ref1="$picture[1]" ref2="$picture[1]" onmouseover="Biz.Product.Product.ChangePic(this);" class="Picture40"/></a></li>';
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Echo out the variables you're trying to use in HTML

```
<li class="moveUnit">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" class="currentItem">
        <img src="<?php echo $picture[1] ?>" alt=""
             ref1="<?php echo $picture[1] ?>" ref2="<?php echo $picture[1] ?>"
             onmouseover="Biz.Product.Product.ChangePic(this);" class="Picture40"/>
    </a>
</li>
```